# Using variables?

Tags: java, android, substitution

I'm trying to learn android java programming and I have a question. I have a few views that I wish to navigate between. I'm trying to figure out if I can use a variable in place of the actual view name? Such as
`previous_view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` Where previous_view would be substituted for the actual name obtained from a list.

I don't know what to search for and I am not asking for code. I just need a starting point for my search.

Edit:

I am using the following code to track my views with a list

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){
  @Override
   Public void onClick (View _view){
  if (view1.getVisibility() ==     View.VISIBLE){
  current_view = "view1";
  List.add(current_view);
  listview1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, List));

  ((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I am using this to try to retrieve my values.

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed(){
 previous_view = List.get((int)(List.size()-2));
 previous_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

My problem is how do I make previous_view, which returns view1, work with the line set as `previous_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: as far as I can understand : you have a number of views `view1`,`view2`,`view3` and so on and you want to apply some common operation to each of these. Is it what you want?

Comment: Each View Represent by a Class . So you use a variable for this instance of view .. Is this what you are asking /??

Comment: @Doc You have the right of it. When I click on a button, I want to set view1 to GONE and set another to VISIBLE. Then onBackPressed I want to essentially reverse the process. It was suggested that I track my views with a list. I can do that, but I don't know how to set the (view).setVisibility using a common event. Such as prev_view.setVisibility. I have a simple list string value like view1 entered in my list string and I can retrieve it into a string variable. But setting the variable so that it can be used by setVisibility illudes me.

Answer (score 0):

Try move in this direction:

Your class must implement `View.OnFocusChangeListener`

Define member variable for previous view:

```
View mPrevView = getCurrentFocus();
```

Next, override method:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
   //in this section you can do something with previous focused view
   //(even call method)
   //and then update view;
   mPrevView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   mPrevView = v;
}
```